# Crout LU decomposition in R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

Just wondering if anybody would share an implementation of the Crout algorithm for a LU decomposition (A = L * U) in R. There's a lu function in pracma library but uses Doolite instead.

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -10   30   50
[2,]   -6   16   22
[3,]   -2    1   -5
> lu(A)
$L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.0    0
[2,]  0.6  1.0    0
[3,]  0.2  2.5    1

$U
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -10   30   50
[2,]    0   -2   -8
[3,]    0    0    5
```

Whereas for the Crout algorithm you'd get something like this instead:

```
$L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -10    0    0
[2,]   -6   -2    0
[3,]   -2   -5    5

$U
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   -3   -5
[2,]    0    1    4
[3,]    0    0    1
```

I've been googling for something like that for a while but didn't found any working implementation in R.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not on the right site. Try Software Recommendation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust How so? I'm asking for a function in language R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not difficult to convert some MATLAB code to an R implementation:

```
LUcrout <- function(A) {
    n <- nrow(A)
    L <- matrix(0, n, n); U <- matrix(0, n, n)
    for (i in 1:n) {
        L[i, 1] <- A[i, 1]
        U[i, i] <- 1
    }
    for (j in 2:n) {
        U[1, j] <- A[1, j] / L[1, 1]
    }
    for (i in 2:n) {
        for (j in 2:i) {
            L[i, j] <- A[i, j] - L[i, 1:(j-1)] %*% U[1:(j-1), j]
        }
        if (i < n) {
            for (j in ((i+1):n)) {
                U[i, j] = (A[i, j] - L[i, 1:(i-1)] %*% U[1:(i-1), j]) / L[i, i]
            }
        }
    }
    return(list(L = L, U = U))
}
```

Applied to your matrix A example it returns

```
A = matrix(c(-10, 30, 50,
              -6, 16, 22,
              -2,  1, -5), 3, 3, byrow = TRUE)

> LUcrout(A)
$L
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  -10    0    0
[2,]   -6   -2    0
[3,]   -2   -5    5

$U
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1   -3   -5
[2,]    0    1    4
[3,]    0    0    1
```

which is not the same as what you suggested, but is identical to what MATLAB returns (see the 'Crout-matrix-decomposition' page on Wikipedia).

LU decompositions are not unique. Which advantages does the Crout algorithm have in your opinion?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that doesn't seem to match the expected result. I found that MatLab implementation in Wikipedia myself before and tried to do a more or less literal translation but got into trouble, so I guess "difficult" is a relative term. Probably if you know both MatLab and R would be easy, but I know nothing of MatLab and just started with R. On your question, I'm not aware of any advantage of Crout over Doolittle, it's just something convenient to have for academic purposes.

Comment: Oh, I see your implementation is right, what seems to be wrong is the data I put in the question. Lol! I'll fix that. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Take the Doolittle decomposition of A transpose, swap L and U and take their transposes.

Comment: Tried that, but it's not producing the expected result. According to that t(lu(t(A))$U) should match Crout L, but it does not. If you didn't mean that, could you add some sample code? thanks!

Comment: This actually works too, just realised there was something wrong with the sample I put in the question, nonetheless Hans answer is more thorough and provides actual code, so I've accepted that one.