# R Code for LU Factorization for a Banded Matrix

Tags: r, matrix, bandwidth

Use R to implement an algorithm to compute the LU factorization of banded matrices (you can ignore pivoting). The inputs to your function should be a matrix A and its bandwidth w (your algorithm does not need to determine the bandwidth, you can assume it will be provided by the user). The outputs should be a list of two matrices L and U .

```
lu_with_bandwidth <- function(A, bandwidth) {
  n <- nrow(A)
  L <- diag(n)
  U <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
  
  for (i in 1:n) {
    start_col <- max(1, i - bandwidth)
    end_col <- min(n, i + bandwidth)
    
    U[i, i:end_col] <- A[i, i:end_col]
    
    if (start_col <= end_col) {
      L[start_col:end_col, i] <- A[start_col:end_col, i] / U[i, i]
      if (i < n) {
        A[(i+1):end_col, (i+1):end_col] <- A[(i+1):end_col, (i+1):end_col] - L[(i+1):end_col, i] %*% U[i, (i+1):end_col]
      }
    }
  }
  
  return(list(L = L, U = U))
}
B <- matrix (c(3,1,4,0,0,0,1,5,9,2,0,0,6,5,3,5,8,0,0,9,7,9,3,2,0,0,3,8,4,6,0,0,0,2,6,4), nrow=6)
print(lu_with_bandwidth(B,2))
```

Output error: Error in A[(i + 1):end_col, (i + 1):end_col] - L[(i + 1):end_col, i] %*%  :
non-conformable arrays

here is the algorithm i follow.
[algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJftx.png)

Comment: You should add code to print the dimensions of all the matrices at each step just before the error-generating line. That A matrix looks to be square but L and U look to be row and column  matrices.

Comment: @IRTFM I tried to add this earlier,

cat("Dimensions of L[start_col:end_col, i]:", dim(L[start_col:end_col, i]), "\n")
cat("Dimensions of U[i, (i+1):end_col]:", dim(U[i, (i+1):end_col]), "\n")

but I still have no clue

Comment: If you don’t give the results of your efforts at debugging, then we also “have no clue”.

Comment: @IRTFM So, I added those two lines after if (i < n) {, and it gave me Dimensions of L[start_col:end_col, i]: 
Dimensions of U[i, (i+1):end_col]: 
Error in A[(i + 1):end_col, (i + 1):end_col] - L[(i + 1):end_col, i] %*%  : 
  non-conformable arrays. It didn't even give me the dimension, which I was not sure why.

Comment: At the point where the error it thrown the first term in the RHS of the assignment is a 2x2 matrix while the result of the matrix multiplication (the second term) is a 1x1 matrix. Hence the non-conformable error message.

Comment: The latest edit still does not appear to follow the algorithm.. The algorithm has three conditionals inside the loops. Yours has 4. It also appears to specify a different range than you are using: [1,i] whereas you are using [1,i-1]

Comment: @IRTFM hm, isnt i have on 3 conditional (if, else if, and else)? the last one is for my matrix L

Comment: I see three different assignments to U in your code and only 2 assignments to U in the algorithm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70711447/crout-lu-decomposition-in-r

Comment: @IRTFM i kind of get it now. may i ask something else. so, now we have L and U at the end. what if i want to do matrix multiplication on them. i tried to do return (list(L%*%U)) but it gives me nothing

Comment: I’m not sure what is meant by “nothing” because I have not seen the full input data and code.

Comment: @IRTFM ok lets say i take your code below, but after line return(list(L=L, U=U)) i add return (list(L%*%U)). the output is only matrix L and U without giving me the result of matrix multiplication of L and U

Comment: That's not what I get when I change the function definition. Check your spelling of the function names.

Comment: This version of your question has already received [an answer](/a/77078926). If you have a different but related question you can [ask a new one](/questions/ask). If you have found an answer to *this* question you can "Post Your Answer" by clicking the button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the drop=FALSE parameter to the indexing of L and U you will get further. R's `[` function will drop dimensions for single column or row matrices.

```
  ... - L[(i+1):end_col, i, drop=FALSE] %*% U[i, (i+1):end_col, drop=FALSE]
```

```
#no prettying screen scraping:
> lu_with_bandwidth <- function(A, bandwidth) {
+     n <- nrow(A)
+     L <- diag(n)
+     U <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
+     
+     for (i in 1:n) {
+         start_col <- max(1, i - bandwidth)
+         end_col <- min(n, i + bandwidth)
+         
+         U[i, i:end_col] <- A[i, i:end_col]
+         
+         if (start_col <= end_col) {
+             L[start_col:end_col, i] <- A[start_col:end_col, i] / U[i, i]
+             if (i < n) {cat("starting")
+                 A[(i+1):end_col, (i+1):end_col] <- A[(i+1):end_col, (i+1):end_col] - L[(i+1):end_col, i, drop=FALSE] %*% U[i, (i+1):end_col, drop=FALSE]
+             }
+         }
+     }
+     
+     return(list(L = L, U = U))
+ }
> B <- matrix (c(3,1,4,0,0,0,1,5,9,2,0,0,6,5,3,5,8,0,0,9,7,9,3,2,0,0,3,8,4,6,0,0,0,2,6,4), nrow=6)
> print(lu_with_bandwidth(B,2))
startingstartingstartingstartingstarting$L
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.2142857 -0.6043165  0.0000000  0.0000000 0.0000000
[2,] 0.3333333 1.0000000 -0.3021583  4.0354839  0.0000000 0.0000000
[3,] 1.3333333 1.6428571  1.0000000 -3.4910138  0.1514658 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000 0.4285714 -0.3741007  1.0000000  0.4605723 0.6269144
[5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 -0.8057554 -1.4677419  1.0000000 2.8008919
[6,] 0.0000000 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.8967742 -0.1100977 1.0000000

$U
     [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     [,6]
[1,]    3 1.000000  6.000000  0.000000  0.000000 0.000000
[2,]    0 4.666667  3.000000  9.000000  0.000000 0.000000
[3,]    0 0.000000 -9.928571 -7.785714  3.000000 0.000000
[4,]    0 0.000000  0.000000  2.230216  9.122302 2.000000
[5,]    0 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 19.806452 8.935484
[6,]    0 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 3.190228
```

But I don't know if that is correct or not. (It does have a banded structure so it might be.)

Comment: the code is almost correct. It tackles the error and actually produce the right U. However, now I am confused because for the L factor, it should be a lower triangular matrix. Honestly the value for the lower triangular are all correct. I jus not sure why there are value filled in the upper triangular part

Comment: You were making assignments to rectangular sub matrices of L. Perhaps you should have indexed that assignment with `lower.tri`? Where is the algorithm you are following?

Comment: the algorithm is too long to put in the comment, i update my prompt instead. it should be similar to LU factorization, but i only want to work with nonzero element as it is a banded matrix.

Comment: The algorithm should have been put in the body of the question as should have been any code or results. I’m willing to look at this again only if you do so.

Comment: Yes, I have been put my algorithm in the body of the question. It is a link that lead you to a picture (algorithm in blue). Here for easy reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJftx.png

Comment: The algorithm has an outer and an inner loop. You only have one for loop in your code. It looks to me that you forgot the loop that manages the “j” index. That could explain why you are getting values in the triangle that should be only 0’s.

Comment: I modified my code https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwriP.png but it stills give me wrong answer

Comment: Images of code are against the principles of SO. Paste it into your question as text code block. (but don't wait around for any response. It's bedtime here on the West Coast.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to SO. I have updated my code and give the output of my code. I hope you have a great rest